# How should I increase the resolution of an image outputted by SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm currently using the preview function of SymPy, with viewer set to "file". The link below should lead to an image that I made through SymPy.

[image]

My code:

```py
from sympy.printing.preview import preview
preview(content, viewer="file", filename=filename)
```

Is there a way to increase the resolution of the image, or make it sharper?

Comment: Please share some example code.   You can change the settings via matplotlib's [`plt.rcParams`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rcParams), for instance calling `plt.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 600` before saving

Comment: I'm directly using SymPy for this. I'm not familiar with the internals of SymPy, so it may use matplotlib, but I'm not sure how I can apply your comment.

Comment: If you don't create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it is hard to show what to do exactly. In essence, you just `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` and then write `plt.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 600 `.  Sympy makes full use of matplotlib for plotting. All the rest happens automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the DPI in the `dvioptions` argument.

```
preview(content, viewer="file", filename=filename, dvioptions=['-D','1200'])
```